# Is there a closed form for $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2+a^2} dx$?

Tags: integration

As the title says, is there a closed form for
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2+a^2} dx \,?
$$

The one with $\cos(x)$ instead of $\sin(x)$ can be calculated via a simple application of the Residue theorem, but the computation uses the fact that the function is even, so the same trick does not work for this one.

**Clarification** In case this was unclear, I do not care about the method used to calculate this integral.

Comment: Hint: $$\sin(x) = \operatorname{Im}e^{ix}.$$

Comment: @vitamind I do not see how that does any difference. I think that would help if the integral would be the PV over the reals, but it is not.

Comment: I can not see why there is a problem with the the integration domain. The countour path has to be a little different.

Comment: @vitamind That is the problem, I cannot find a good contour path. Note that since $e^0=1$, switching to the exponential seems to create issues with the extra piece of the contour path.

Comment: @vitamind For $\cos(x)/(x^2+a^2)$ we can compute the integral on the whole of real line by the residue at $ai$, and halve it to give 0 to infinity.  This trick doesn't work here for $\sin$ instead.

Comment: I think if you choose a clever path it might work. Maybe you are right and it is not possible.

Comment: Use, on the result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3261690) the Feynman's trick (differentiation under the integral sign with respect to parameter $c$)

Comment: Can we use identity $\cos x=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)$ and the fact that we can calculate integral with the cosine?

Comment: I'm not sure about this path: Starting at $0$ going up to $ai-i\varepsilon$ semi-cirle that includes $ai$ to $ai+i\varepsilon$ going up to $iR$ and coming back to the real axis with a quarter circle with radius $R$ and then back to the origin.

Comment: @vitamind That doesn't work -- along the imaginary axis the denominator becomes $a^2-x^2$ instead of $x^2+a^2$ and there is no easy way to relate them.

Comment: @user10354138 I think an undesired factor of $x$ comes up if we try your $\int_0^1$ suggestion.

Comment: There might be a way to derive an ODE for this integral, like in the following answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1841104/269624

Comment: @YuriyS I think he's trying to find a way via complex analysis

Comment: By the way, WA gives an ugly closed form in terms of exponential integrals, even for a=1, so the answer is yes, there's a closed form, but not elementary

Comment: Perhaps you could use $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin xt}{t^2+a^2}dt=\mathcal{L}\left\{\frac{\log(a/s)}{a^2-s^2}\right\}(x),$$ where $\mathcal{L}^{-1}$ is the inverse Laplace transform

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 4):

Contour integration of $(e^{iz}-e^{-a})/(a^2+z^2)$ along the boundary of $|z|<R,0<\arg z<\pi/2$, with $z=ia$ a removable singularity (we assume $a>0$), yields $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{a^2+x^2}\,dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-a}}{a^2-x^2}\,dx,$$ expressible in terms of the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) function (after doing partial fractions).

Comment: This is a nice way to show that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{a^{2}+x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx = \frac{\pi}{2a} e^{-a}$.

Answer (score 4):

First, we enforce the substitution $x\mapsto ax$.  Then, we use the convolution theorem of the Fourier Transform to write

$$\begin{align}
I(a)&\equiv \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2+a^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac1a\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(ax)}{x^2+1}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac1a \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(ax)}{x^2+1}\,H(x)\,dx\\\\
&=\frac1a\text{Im}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{H(x)}{x^2+1}e^{iax}\,dx\right)\\\\
&=\frac1{2\pi a} \text{Im}\left(\left(\pi e^{-|a|}\right)*\left(\pi \delta(a)+\text{PV}\left(\frac ia\right)\right)\right)\\\\
&=\frac1{2a}\text{PV}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-|a-a'|}}{a'}\,da'\right)\\\\
&=\frac{e^{-a}\text{Ei}(a)-e^{a}\text{Ei}(-a)}{2a}
\end{align}$$

where $\text{Ei}(a)=\int_{-\infty}^a \frac{e^{x}}{x}\,dt$ is the exponential integral, interpreted in the Cauchy Principal Value sense for $a>0$.

Comment: Though being familiar with Fourier Transform and distributions, I am not sure to understand how you obtain (5th line) this convolution... Could you give some detail ?

Comment: @JeanMarie The [convolution theorem] for the Fourier Transform (for tempered distributions) is discussed [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem#Convolution_theorem_for_tempered_distributions).  And [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) is a more detailed discussion.  The Fourier transform of the Heaviside function, $H$, can be found [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269809/heaviside-step-function-fourier-transform-and-principal-values).

Comment: Oh, I understand now that you consider the expression on the 4th line as the (imaginary part of the inverse) F.T. of the product $H(x) . \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$, therefore equal to the conolution of their F.T. .... This astute way (+1) deserves indeed a small explanation, don't you think ?...

Comment: @jeanmarie Pleased to hear that you understand.  I had thought the second sentence before the development would suffice as an explanation.  Now, with our comments, the reader is well equipped.  Thank you for your very thoughtful comments.  I hope you're doing well.  Stay safe and healthy my friend.

Comment: I don't think your answer needs any more improvement (I already upvoted it, as I said you in a comment).

Comment: @JeanMarie That message was directed explicitly to the OP.

Comment: I have already upvoted your answer that I find, as it is now, very understandable. Maybe give a reference to the Fourier transform of $H(x)$

Comment: @JeanMarie That last comment was directed to the OP.  But as a reference to the FT of the Heaviside function, you can find one [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73922/fourier-transform-of-unit-step),  and another [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269809/heaviside-step-function-fourier-transform-and-principal-values).

Comment: @N .S. Hi! It's been a while.  I hope you're stayed safe and healthy during the pandemic. If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)